# How to create a Q-Q plot with Poisson as theoretical distribution

Tags: r, plot, quantile, poisson

I need to create a Q-Q plot in order to check if my observed data fits a Poisson distribution.

Here is my data.frame:

```
df = read.table(text = 'Var1 Freq
 1975   10
 1976   12
 1977    9
 1978   14
 1979   14
 1980   11
 1981    8
 1982    7
 1983   10
 1984    8
 1985   12
 1986    9
 1987   10
 1988    9
 1989   10
 1990    9
 1991   11
 1992   12
 1993    9
 1994   10', header = TRUE)
```

The `df$Freq` column is the one that interests me as the observations represent the count of events per year.

I know I have to use the `qqplot` function and also the `qpois` one to create the theoretical quantiles, but how?

Comment: Your data is not Poisson-distributed. What makes you think that it is?

Comment: Thanks. I just need a statistical confirmation of what you said :)

Comment: I don' t understand what you're trying to do. Your data is *obviously* non-Poisson. Look e.g. at the CDF for lambda=1 `x <- seq(1975, 1994); plot(x, ppois(x, 1));` or the PMF `plot(x, rpois(x, 1))`.

Comment: I have a feeling there might be a misconception about either the [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) or the purpose of [Q-Q plots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q%E2%80%93Q_plot), or both.

Comment: @MauritsEvers, I'm curious why you think there is a misconception here.  It seems reasonable to me to use a QQ plot to visualize the comparison of the empirical vs the theoretical distribution.

Comment: I object to the blind use of a statistical method to explore and interpret data (misconception #1). OPs data contains the distribution of events as a function of years. If we assume `k = [1975, 1994]`, then the data is obviously non-Poisson (misconception #2). This interpretation would be supported by the fact that the column is labelled frequency `df$Freq`. One could think about fitting a shifted (and potentially zero-truncated) Poisson distribution, but I think this goes beyond what OP wanted.

Comment: [continued] If however, OP is interested in the *(frequency) distribution of the frequencies*, `Var1` is irrelevant, should have been omitted from the data, and the original question should be rephrased. Either way, this was clearly your interpretation as well @Benjamin.

Comment: Oh. That's so obvious now. I'm kind of embarrassed I missed it. Thanks for elaborating, @mauritsEvers

Comment: Nothing to be embarrassed about @Benjamin. I hadn't thought about your interpretation and considered it a trivial case until you posted your solution. Now I'm actually curious to know what OP is after.

Answer (score 5):

Also, the `fitdistrplus` package can do this with much less code. Compares the empirical and theoretical density and CDFs.

```
library('fitdistrplus')
plot(fitdist(df$Freq,"pois"))
```

You can get your lambda, etc. and check against other distributions as well. Not as flexible as the `ggplot` approach, but good for a quick check.

Answer (score 2):

`ggplot2` has a nice interface for doing this.  Here's a QQ plot with an agreement step line in red.  The QQ plot is made using `stat_qq` and changing the `distribution` argument.  You'll need to provide `lambda` in the `dparams` argument.

```
ggplot(data = df,
       mapping = aes(sample = Freq)) + 
  stat_qq(distribution = stats::qpois,
          dparams = list(lambda = mean(df$Freq))) + 
  geom_step(data = data.frame(x = 6:16,
                              Freq = 6:16),
            mapping = aes(x = x,
                          y = Freq),
            colour = "red",
            alpha = 0.5)
```

Comment: thanks @Benjamin! I just posted my own answer..if you can have a look and tell me if you spot any mistake.

Answer (score 2):

here my possible answer:

```
#calculate Frequencies
tbl = as.data.frame(table(df$Freq))

#create theoretical poisson distr
dist = dpois(1:7, lambda = mean(tbl$Freq))
dist = dist * 20              #make values in the same scale as tbl$Freq (20 = sum(tbl$Freq))
dist = as.data.frame(dist)
dist$Var1 = tbl$Var1

#qqplot
qqplot(dist$dist, tbl$Freq, xlab = 'Theoretical Quantiles', ylab = 'Empirical Quantiles',
       main = 'Q-Q plot Poisson', xlim = c(0,5), ylim = c(0,5))
abline(0,1) #create 45° line
```

If you spot any mistake please let me know. Thanks